# REST API to SOAP proxy cause NULLPAYLOAD error

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, esb, mule-studio

I am following REST API to SOAP proxy example, i have changed which WS should to connect and Json structure, when i run the project i got an error of NULLPAYLOAD. when testing using APIKIT

below is my configuration and after it error.

Thanks for the help

```
     <http:listener-config name="api-httpListenerConfig" host="localhost" port="8888" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <api-platform-gw:api id="rest-api-howto-api" apiName="rest-api-howto-api" version="1.0.0" flowRef="api-main" create="true" doc:name="API Autodiscovery">
    </api-platform-gw:api>
    <apikit:config name="api-config" raml="api.raml" consoleEnabled="true" consolePath="console" doc:name="Router"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://localhost:9000/SoapContext/SoapPort?wsdl" service="WSStudentRoasterWebService" port="WSStudentRoasterPort" serviceAddress="http://localhost:9000/SoapContext/SoapPort" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <flow name="api-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        <apikit:router config-ref="api-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
        <exception-strategy ref="api-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="get:/loan:api-config">
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform to SOAP Request" metadata:id="8c106b2f-1c34-43a4-bac8-d1627b7b6f42">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json" doc:sample="sample_data/json.json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml

%namespace ns0 http://xxx.edu
---
{
    ns0#NewStudentData: {
        RoasterSend: {
            messageID: payload.loan.MSG
        }
    }

}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="NewStudentData" doc:name="SOAP WebService"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform from SOAP Response">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%namespace ns0 http://www.mulesoft.com/schemas/Mule/Schema.xsd
%namespace ns01 http://xxx.edu
---
{
    loan: {
        MSG: payload.ns01#NewStudentDataResponse.StudentRoaster_result.messageID
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
    <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy name="api-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Resource not found&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="405">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.MethodNotAllowedException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Method not allowed&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="415">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Unsupported media type&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="406">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotAcceptableException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Not acceptable&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="400">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.BadRequestException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Bad request&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
    </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
```

the error i am getting is below

```
INFO 2016-12-01 10:21:53,203 [[rest-api-howto_1.0.0].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.01] org.mule.component.simple.LogComponent:
********************************************************************************
* Message received in service: api-main. Content is: ‘{NullPayload}’ *
********************************************************************************
ERROR 2016-12-01 10:21:53,212 [[rest-api-howto_1.0.0].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message : Exception while executing:
{NullPayload}
^
Unexpected character ‘N’ at payload@[1:2] (line:column), expected ‘”‘.
Payload : {NullPayload}
Element XML :
%dw 1.0%output application/xml%namespace ns0 http://xxx.edu—{ns0#NewStudentData: {RoasterSend: {messageID: payload.loan.MSG}}}
Payload Type : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element : /get:\/loan:api-config/processors/0 @ rest-api-howto_1.0.0:rest-api-soap.xml:23 (Transform to SOAP Request)
———————————————————————-
```